# How can I route a cable around a floor joist over a wall?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I had to pull some drywall off because of a leak. I found that this wire was right under the drywall. It didn’t have any metal strap in front or anything. It runs down the side of that 2x4 and crosses the other 2x4. The drywall was installed over that whole section except for the 2x4 on the left. The 2x4 on the left is where the garage door is attached to.

I can see why they did it as the joist is right there and the wire is coming from above. So how would I route it correctly?

[image]

The circled section at the top is where the issue is. The bottom Circle is where it goes.

There’s not much slack above but it’s an attic like area, so a junction box could go up there.

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to provide a picture standing at least 6 feet away?

Comment: It really depends on where it goes and how much slack you have available. We can't see from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be drilling from the plate through the header straight up the center , with it centered it will be ok and no nail plate would be required it will not be a problem with strength as the load is on studs at the opening.

Comment: Looks like the header is made up of two 2x12 that with metal brackets with a slight gap between them. So I might be able to put it down the middle like you said. The difficult part will be getting over to that side.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get some flexible metal conduit, slide it onto the portion of the wire that isn't well enough recessed, add anti-short bushings and then just drywall it again.  Leave a notch path in the drywall for the armored cable then using concrete fill and tape over the notched area.

Since the wire is feeding an exterior outlet you can just pull it back from the outlet slide the flexible metal conduit on top and re-secure.

Comment: Hm, are you after flexible metal conduit?

Comment: It’s an exterior outlet. The piece on the left was not covered, but the piece at the top was covered.